# AssertionError at /posts/ 'PostList' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method

Tags: django, django-views

```py
ERROR in url==http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/
 D:\Priyanka_Angular1\virtual_env\django-angular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in dispatch

                response = self.handle_exception(exc)

     ...

▶ Local vars
D:\Priyanka_Angular1\virtual_env\django-angular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in handle_exception

                self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

     ...

▶ Local vars
D:\Priyanka_Angular1\virtual_env\django-angular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py in dispatch

                response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

     ...

▶ Local vars
D:\Priyanka_Angular1\virtual_env\django-angular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py in get

            return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

     ...

▶ Local vars
D:\Priyanka_Angular1\virtual_env\django-angular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py in list

            queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

     ...

▶ Local vars
D:\Priyanka_Angular1\virtual_env\django-angular\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py in get_queryset

                % self.__class__.__name__
```

`serializer.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from posts.models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.Field(source='author.username')
    api_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_api_url')
 
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'created_on', 'author', 'url', 'api_url')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'created_on')
 
    def get_api_url(self, obj):
         return "#/post/%s" % obj.id
```

`views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from posts.models import Post
from posts.serializers import PostSerializer
 
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  """
   List all boards, or create a new board.
  """
  model = Post
  serializer_class = PostSerializer
 
 
class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  """
   Retrieve, update or delete a board instance.
  """
  model = Post
  serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to include `queryset = Post.objects.all()` in your `PostList` view, as well as in `PostDetail`.

Every view needs a queryset defined to know what objects to look for. You define the view's queryset by using the `queryset` attribute (as I suggested) or returning a valid queryset from a `get_queryset` method.

By the way, you can get rid of the `model` attribute in your views as they aren't used. That's not the correct way to tell the view what objects to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Need to just include in **views.py** and create **serializers.py**

views.py
from autentication.serializers import TestSerializer

```
authentication_classes = ()
permission_classes = ()
serializer_class = TestSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class TestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
```

Note : Python 3.8.x with djangorestframework 3.11.x

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

model = Post use queryset=Post.objects.all()

It should word perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use generics with RetrieveAPIView and my simple mistake

error code

```
class PizzeriaRetrieveAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = "id"
    querysets = Pizzeria.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzeriaDetailSerializer
```

and fixed code, i removed "s" from querysets ->  queryset

```
class PizzeriaRetrieveAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = "id"
    queryset = Pizzeria.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzeriaDetailSerializer
```

everything works fine, somethimes we mistake a small changes...